# Either in need of a or requires

Tags: usage

I think **is in need of a wash** is more appropriate choice to fill in the following blank

> The brown shirt_________.

Because meaning of **in need of** is  [Macmilan](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.macmillandictionary.com/amp/dictionary/british/in-need-of-something)

But the right choice in my book is **requires a wash**

Comment: Both expressions are perfectly acceptable English.  Does your book give any guidelines that limit the choice, e.g. number of words?

Comment: Sadly, such tuition books frequently just reflect the views of the author rather than justifying them.

Comment: @Kate Bunting No

Answer (score 0):

The most idiomatic English (American) would be ‘needs’. The phrase ‘requires a...’ is more formal than ‘In need of a’. So I would expect ‘requires’ to be used only in a more formal, perhaps business, setting.